# Java array order

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I have the following array:

> int [] mi_array= {9,4,0,0,4,0,3,0,1,8,0};

I want to order the numbers other than 0 on the left, and the 0s on the right, but I find that the function steps on one of the numbers.

The output must be

> {9,4,4,3,1,8,0,0,0,0,0}

```
public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] mi_array= {9,4,4,3,1,8,0,0,0,0,0};
        
        int x=0;
        int y=mi_array.length-1;
        for (int i=0;i<mi_array.length;i++)
            
        
            if(mi_array[i]!=0) {
        
                mi_array[x]=mi_array[i];
                x++;
            }
            else {              
                mi_array[y]=mi_array[i];
                y--;
            }
            
        for (int i=0;i<mi_array.length;i++)
            
            System.out.println(mi_array[i]);
            System.out.println(x);
            
}
    
}
```

Comment: Actually non-zeroes should go to the left, I expressed myself wrong, the order doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `IntStream.concat` to merge the parts of the array that are not 0 with the parts that are.

```
final int[] mi_array = { 9, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 1, 8, 0 };
final int[] result = IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(mi_array).filter(i -> i != 0), 
    Arrays.stream(mi_array).filter(i -> i == 0)).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

[Demo!](https://ideone.com/Wt8sit)

You can also do this:

```
final int[] mi_array = { 9, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 1, 8, 0 };
final int[] result = new int[mi_array.length];
final AtomicInteger idx = new AtomicInteger();
Arrays.stream(mi_array).filter(i -> i != 0).forEach(val -> result[idx.getAndIncrement()] = val);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
int[] mi_array = {9, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 1, 8, 0};
for (int i = 0, j = i + 1, s = mi_array.length; j < s;)
    if (mi_array[i] == 0) {
        mi_array[i] = mi_array[j];
        mi_array[j] = 0;
        ++j;
    } else if (++i >= j)
        j = i + 1;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mi_array));
// -> [9, 4, 4, 3, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem here is that you overwrite numbers you haven't already covered.

```
   if (mi_array[i] != 0) {
       mi_array[x] = mi_array[i];
       x++;
   }
```

`x` can never exceed `i` in this code; it starts at 0 just like i does, and increments at most by 1 every loop (and i increments by 1 every loop). So, no problem here; at 'worst' this is `mi_array[i] = mi_array[i];` which does nothing.

***however***...

```
    } else {              
      mi_array[y]=mi_array[i];
      y--;
    }
```

This is much more problematic. Given inputs `{9,4,0,0,4,0,3,0,1,8,0};`, when `i` is 2, then `mi_array[i]` is 0, thus this code runs. `y` is still 10, so this will end up running: `mi_array[10] = 0;`. The second 0 occurs when `i` is 3, and ends up running: `mi_array[9] = 0;`. And at that point, the `8` at index 9? **You deleted it**. It cannot be recovered.

### The solution

The dumb solution is to make a copy of the array; edit the copy, refer to the original (which you won't change at all). You don't actually end up needing a copy; this code will write every number back, so just make a new array of the same size and write in that.

A slightly more elegant solution will not write 0s at all. Instead, it just writes the non-zeroes (as that code cannot overwrite anything, as shown before), and then at the end, overwrite the rest with zeroes. Now you don't need a copy.

Answer (score 0):

`O(n)`, two-pointer approach:

```
public static void shiftZeroesRight(int[] array) {    
    int notZeroPos;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] != 0)
            continue;

        notZeroPos = i + 1;
        while (notZeroPos < array.length && array[notZeroPos] == 0)
            ++notZeroPos;
    
        if (notZeroPos >= array.length)
            break;
    
        array[i] = array[notZeroPos];
        array[notZeroPos] = 0;
    }    
}
```